# I'm making a game in Javascript. Is there any benefit to NOT using a framework?

Tags: javascript, frameworks

I know javascript, but I've never learned any libraries or frameworks. I've never used jQuery or Phaser.js or anything like that.

Would it be better for me to spend the time and learn how to use Phaser, or are there actually benefits to handcoding it in javascript?

It's a top-down, 2d, action/adventure dungeon crawler. I know pretty much how I can build the whole game using mostly-simple javascript. But I don't know if doing it this way will inherently make the game more dense and cause it to run slower, or lead to more bugs. On the other hand, maybe it will do just the opposite. Will straight javascript run faster than if I used a framework?

I'm not a master of Javascript. I'm closer to a beginner, but I've made at least 30 or 40 games on codeless softwares like gamemaker and stencyl. I'm familiar with game programming and I've made one game before in Javascript. I know I did a lot of things incorrectly on that first game, So maybe a framework would help?

Comment: Won't know until you try

Comment: I think frameworks give people structure & there are lots of youtube & Udemy courses.. Udemy has a ton of $10 deals from Black Friday. some have been extended into January, but I couldn't say what option is best.  It may be easier to rebuild your original game under a framework before building a new one from scratch. That might help you learn & decide your long-term route.

Answer (score 0):

The main benefit of doing something yourself is that you will learn - but it will be a much slower process.

Everything will take longer.

> Will straight javascript run faster than if I used a framework?"

If you do it from scratch you can invest a lot of time optimising the specific things you need. This time may not pay for itself if its something the framework already does reasonably fast.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a tremendous benefit to understanding the raw language, DOM API, event model, etc.  Every framework has leaky abstractions that will be much less painful to deal with if you understand the (imperfect) language and DOM.

My advice would be to give bare JS/DOM a try first, but understand that both have a lot of legacy baggage.  If that's too painful, try something that abstracts SVG/Canvas or whatever you're planning to use for your game.